# how to dereference a pointer of an object inside another object

Tags: c++, class, dereference

I need to build a set of classes that are dependent on each other. I am having trouble when I pass a pointer to one class to another class that is instantiated inside it.

Here an example to illustrate my problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class base;

//

 child class
    class child
    {
    public:
    child(){};
    void setPointer (base* ptr){pointer = ptr; }
    void printing(){(*pointer).print();} // error C2027: use of undefubed type base
                                        // error C2227: '.print' must have class/struct/union
private:
    base* pointer;
};

// base class
class base
{
public:
    base()
    {
        initial_vec();
        VEC[0].setPointer(this);
        VEC[0].printing();
    }

    void print() { cout <<"printing from BASE"<< endl;}

    void initial_vec ()
    {
        child child1;
        VEC.push_back(child1);
    }

private:
    vector<child> VEC;
};

int main()
{
    base b1;

    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Do you have any idea how I achieve that without getting those errors ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You cannot dereference a forward declaration from inlined code. This must be externed to a separate translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error you are getting it because you are trying to call `printing()` from your `base` class with only a forward declaration.  To fix your problem, define the body of the function `printing()` after your `base` class has been fully defined.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration) is more details on forward declaration.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Do you have any idea how I achieve that without getting those errors ?"*

It's fairly simple. You omit the inlined codeparts that reference `base`, and move tem after the full declaration of the class:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class base;

 child class {
    public:
    child(){};
    void setPointer (base* ptr); // <<< Only declare the functions here
    void printing();

private:
    base* pointer;
};
```

---

```
// base class
class base {
public:
    base()
    {
        initial_vec();
        VEC[0].setPointer(this);
        VEC[0].printing();
    }

    void print() { cout <<"printing from BASE"<< endl;}

    void initial_vec ()
    {
        child child1;
        VEC.push_back(child1);
    }

private:
    vector<child> VEC;
};
```

---

Define the functions after base was fully declared:

```
void child::setPointer (base* ptr){pointer = ptr; }
void child::printing(){(*pointer).print();}

int main() {
    base b1;

    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```